# Terminology confusion with sensitivity used with gain

Tags: sensor, gain, resolution, sensitivity

For force transducers like strain gauges, the resolution is the smallest change in the load that represents a change in the output value of the measured force and moment. The smaller the resolution of a sensor, the larger the sensitivity of the sensor.

Let's say we have a force transducer outputting 1mV/N; if we then amplify this by a gain of 10, it will output 10mV/N.

Does that mean we increased the "overall sensitivity"? Or should the term "sensitivity" only be used when no amplification is applied?

Comment: Did you try asking internet? First hit I got: [Resolution vs Accuracy vs Sensitivity Cutting Through the Confusion](https://www.evaluationengineering.com/home/article/13001199/resolution-vs-accuracy-vs-sensitivity-cutting-through-the-confusion)

Comment: I was not asking the difference between those terms. Something particular to the use of the term when used together with gain.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually call the \$x\$ V/N number the **sensitivity**.

You can add amplification to make that 10 \$x\$ V/N but that does not change the sensitivity of the sensor itself. The amplification only increases the output level.

*What then defines the lowest value we can measure?*

If we would make the applied force lower and lower at some point we would not be able to measure a sensible number anymore due to **noise**. This can be [thermal noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) or induced noise (or radiated signals) emitted by surrounding equipment. The equipment we can remove or shield, the thermal noise we cannot avoid.

Since noise is a random signal it can be "averaged out". A noise signal will have an average value of zero (actually it is a limit function converging to zero) so the longer you measure, the more accurate you measure and the more resolution you get.

Then obviously you can measure slowly changing forces (more time to average) more accurately than quickly changing forces (less time to average).

So: resolution depends on **how fast** you want to measure.

An additional amplifier would amplify **both** noise and the signal (voltage) you actually want to measure so an amplifier by itself does not increase the resolution at all.

Comment: how fast you want to measure ... until you get so slow you're into drift, but then what's drift if it isn't very low frequency noise?

Answer (score 0):

The terms **Resolution, Accuracy, Sensitivity and Sensitivity Analysis** may have different definitions in**Test Engineering** depending on how many input variables are known.

To know the **sensitivity** of any formula, we analyze the signal or control system or component tolerance or sensor measurement system, and simply **take the derivative** of the system **output over input.** this incremental rate may not be linear over the whole range but at least over some range like ESR is Effective Series Resistance, the small changes of  V/I or the error due to supply load variations.   That is a supply to load regulation % error sensitivity.

S{F(x)}= dF/dx such as in your example.

If **uncertainty** includes environmental variations, quantization levels, non-linearity, offset, gain error, Thermal noise, “other” stoichastic noise , unknown transients, repetitive electromagnetic wave interference (EMI), causal errors, non-causal errors, human errors, equipment or component drift out of calibration, etc etc.  Then we have a measurable “uncertainty % or std dev. level” on the absolute values.  That is **a defined NIST traceable accuracy.**

**Resolution** is simply the **smallest** incremental **change** that can be measured. Often it is **misused as the inverse of Sensitivity** when other error factors are unstated or unclear   . It may be used as inverse correctly  with constraints in context  to limits or with a sensitivity affecting resolution  due to other factors like noise, temperature, calibration error, supply voltage, human error. {?}**

**Gain** may improve both resolution and sensitivity IFF (if and only if) the signal to noise ratio is adequate.  Where noise can be DC, AC, random, EMI/RFI, AC hum.

Such as your example : Av= 10 **does increase** the rate or derivative of two linear variables or **Sensitivity**, for the measured parameter and thus lower your resolution.  **But if the error or noise also increases in the signal, then there is no gain in sensitivity**

> Resolution  can also get better with gain but Sensitivity get worse  when it is not done properly, which is a major source of questions in this forum.

Comment: So can that we can increase the overall sensitivity by extra gain but not the resolution? Regarding the example in my question.

Comment: How come resolution gets better with gain?  I thought it is about mechanical properties of the strain gauge.

Comment: If you measure resolution by voltage , NO, but with gain before and measure by strain YES but only if noise is well below, is it?  Not usually with vibration, hysteresis and well designed systems. But on poorly designed systems, maybe if done right

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different perspective, there is a formal definition.

"sensitivity of a measuring system: quotient of the change in an indication of a measuring system and the corresponding change in a value of a quantity being measured".

That being said, all other things kept unchanged, if you increase the gain, yes, you would increase the sensitivity of your *measurement* *system*.

This is just to point out that, according to the formal definition (which is frequently not used precisely in Test Engineering documentation) sensitivity should be applied to *measurement* *systems* and not to *sensors*.

Comment: having been a Test Eng most of my life (among other disciplines) I can agree, yes if you are doing system testing, but no if you are doing sub-system of component testing. and of course a quotient is a simple example or ratio of a partial derivative when linearized by log or whatever transformation